# An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, oracle11g

An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

**Inner exception** : "An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details."

I'm using Oracle as Entity Framework and Database.
When i am trying get result using EF it's working fine. But when i am trying to insert a record into the table I am getting this issue.
This is the code:

```
try{
  Table1 Obj = new Table1();
  Obj.col1 = 2010;
  Obj.col2 =0;
  Obj.col3 = 103907;
  Obj.col4 = 14145;
  DataContext1 dbContext = new DataContext1();
  dbContext.AddToTable1(Obj);

  dbContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(Obj,System.Data.EntityState.Added);
  dbContext.SaveChanges();

}catch(Expectation ex)
  {

  }
```

Comment: Can you show the inner exception?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the inner exception. The issue will probably be obvious from there.

Something like this might help (or set a breakpoint and just look):

```
try{
    Table1 Obj = new Table1();
    Obj.col1 = 2010;
    Obj.col2 =0;
    Obj.col3 = 103907;
    Obj.col4 = 14145;
    DataContext1 dbContext = new DataContext1()
    dbContext.AddToTable1(Obj);      
    dbContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(Obj,System.Data.EntityState.Added);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException e)
    {
        string validationErrors = "DbEntityValidationException ValidationErrors: ";
        foreach (var k in e.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
            foreach (var e1 in k.ValidationErrors)
            {
                validationErrors += string.Format("{0} - {1}; ", e1.PropertyName, e1.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
        throw new Exception(validationErrors, e);
    }
```